# How can Java annotations be used to enforce a coding standard?

Tags: java, annotations, standards

Like the "@Override" annotation which checks for method overriding rules at compile time, can we write a similar custom annotation and enforce our own needs on a method. 
Say i want a method to not to have more than 200 lines. Can i write a custom annotation which when annotated on method will check this requirement in compile time. How can this be done, can someone please elaborate. (code snippets would be helpful, if possible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow this guide about `Annotation Processors`: [Code Generation using Annotation Processors in the Java language – part 2: Annotation Processors](http://deors.wordpress.com/2011/10/08/annotation-processors/)

Explanations and samples inside.

Answer (score 1):

We are using static code analyzing ([PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/) for example), which contains rule about the method size (and many others). Code analyzers have good IDE supports, You should create VCS hooks, or use [CI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) Server to build.